# IIS server allowing specific ip address to hosted sites , Programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, iis

I have some sites hosted in a IIS server , I want to allow the user to access those sites according to their Ip address Which I want to add or remove from a list Programmatically, Is it Possible ?, if it is please suggest me how to do it... Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to add these to a list programmatically? From an admin page or something? Wouldn't an XML file suffice?

Comment: Yes I want handle this list from an admin page. Yes I can store it an xml file but don't know how to allow those ip to the websites.